# SQL data over week_no into columns

Tags: sql, exasolution

I would like to transpose the following SQL result:

<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>sum</kbd>  <kbd>week_no</kbd>
<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>22</kbd>          
<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>24</kbd>

into table like this:

<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>week_22</kbd><kbd>week_23</kbd><kbd>week_24</kbd>
<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>0</kbd>             <kbd>2</kbd>

How could I achieve this on Oracle? Thanks! (I am supposed to consider weekly data over many years, so building cases is not an option)

Comment: If you don't have a fixed set of column names in advance, then this is a SQL anti-pattern.  Transpose / Pivot your data in your application's presentation layer, not the database.

Comment: My problem is that the software I am currently on - Exasol, does not support pivot function and the only way around they suggest is the multiple CASE WHEN scenario.

Comment: http://oraclecoder.com/tutorials/three-ways-to-transpose-rows-into-columns-in-oracle-sql--160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly I have assumed this query on your sample data where it will fill the gaps of week no and Pivot the result set

```
Select A,[22] [week_22],[23] [week_23],[24] [week_24] from (
Select A,Sum,Weekno from Table 
UNION
Select * from ( 
SELECT  top 1 t1.A,'' AS Sum,t1.Weekno-1 AS Weekno
FROM     Table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         Table  t2 
ON       t2.Weekno=t1.Weekno-1 
WHERE    t2.Weekno IS NULL 
AND      t1.Weekno > 0     
ORDER BY t1.Weekno desc )T)TT
PIVOT (MAX(SUM) FOR WEEKNO IN ([22],[23],[24]))PVT
```